# Setting AWS configurations on EMR startup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr

I have a few config files that I changed on my EMR cluster such as the `zeppelin-env.sh`, `zeppelin-site.xml` or `tmux.conf`.
In each file I do minor changes such as add a few `export` lines. I', happy with those confs and now I want them all to be there on start up.
I can save those conf files on my S3 and `aws cp` them with a bootstrap action but this feels like an overkill for a few line changes.

What is the best practice to change conf files on cluster creation?

Comment: I now realize it's fairly easy to change `zeppelin-env` but I still am not sure on with to do with `zeppelin-site.xml` and other apps I `yum install` with bootstrap actions.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing a bootstrap action is designed for :)

Comment: Thank, I just read the bootstrap actions happens before all installations. So I'. still not sure hot to change the `zeppelin-site.xml` using that method.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `zeppelin-site.xml` is unneeded as everything can be overridden using the `zeppelin-env.sh`, which in turn can be configured with the [configurations API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html).
For application that I install using a BA, I will `aws s3 cp` per Henry's advice.